# excell formula to bring other cells in middle of a text

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have a excel file whth multiple columns, I am writing a title which is to combine multiple cells with text i am writing, 
eg, i will have (then text from cell B2) then more text (then text from cell E2) then more text (then value from column M2)

Comment: explore CONCATENATE function from Excel help. Please show us sample data and what you are trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ampersand & , to join contents of cells or text : 
="text"&B2&"more"&E2

Very handy...

Should work - wrote it on my smartphone so not tested